# How to achieve non blocking with Coroutines

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to achieve non IO blocking coroutines (kotlin) in a way that will gain more network calls than threads. It is clear how to use coroutines in a way that doesn't block the main thread, however eventually each coroutine runs within a tread and a network calls blocks that thread (for comparison, using NodeJS allows to reuse the working thread while other requests are waiting for the response to come back).

My use case is that for each incoming request I need to make 2-3 independent external calls, aggregate the response and return. Doing that sequentially is a waste of time. Doing that in parallel will require my service to run about 2-3 times the number of incoming threads (making it about 1K of threads just for waiting for IO).

Many of the couroutine examples are using `delay`, and by that allowing to reuse the threads for multiple couroutine concurrently. However by actually using the real live use case of network calling, I cannot achieve that.

What am I missing? How can I suspend the coroutine until the external service responds?

For example, this example runs only on 5 threads, but reuses the threads over the 1000 calls so it all ends within ~100ms (each dealy is 100ms)

```
val myPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5).asCoroutineDispatcher()
runBlocking {
  (1..1000).forEach {
    launch(myPool) {
      delay(100)
    }
  }
}
```

As opposed to this, that actually runs only 5 concurrent calls over 5 threads, and continue to the next only once is finished. **I wish to have all calls executed "in parallel", taking advantage of sending a request while waiting for the response - just as done in NodeJS**:

```
val restTemplate = RestTemplate()
val myPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5).asCoroutineDispatcher()
runBlocking {
  (1..1000).forEach {
    launch(myPool) {
      restTemplate.getForObject("http://myTest.com", String::class.java) // Say it takes 100ms to response
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to add modifier `suspend` to the `restTemplate.getForObject(...)` function?

Comment: As written bellow - yes, I've tried, and no - did not help. The example bellow you've used is with `delay` which works on all examples, but real IO waiting code is not performing the same.

Comment: It seems what you are trying to achieve is not possible in Kotlin. When you make request in working thread, it will be busy while it is waiting for the response. If you have for example a thread pool of 5 threads, 6 requests and you already running 5 requests in parallel, the sixth request will wait until some of previous requests is finished to free one of the threads. Could you please point me to the docs where I can read about "NodeJS allows to reuse the working thread while other requests are waiting for the response to come back".

Comment: Node.js is a single threaded process by definition. All the code is executed within a single thread, with the event loop managing the concurrency of your tasks. There are many applications running node.jss a web server serving multiple requests at the same time. You can find more about it at https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Comment: Moreover, I find it quite disappointing that this is not possible via Kotlin. If that is the case, what are all the `delay` examples for? All examples shows (including the one you demonstrated) shows how more tasks than threads can be executed, however delay is not a real world use case, and once using real world use case this does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin coroutines aren't magic that turns your blocking network operations into non-blocking. They only allow you to use an asynchronous networking implementation without the cruft of futures and callbacks.

So, in order to proceed,

- Step 1. Find an asynchronous REST library
- Step 2. Write a bit of Kotlin code to bridge the library's native callback-based or future-based API to Kotlin coroutines.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. What still is a mystery to me is what are all the examples with `delay` good for. The demonstrate a concept which is not a real-world use case. And using the asynchronous REST libraries can achieve the same with pure Java

Comment: They are good for demonstrating how your code would look in general, without involving the details of a specific library. In real code you'd have a network call in place of  `delay`. The network call would be non-blocking, yet you'd have plain sequential code. You can't achieve the same with pure Java.

Answer (score 0):

"I wish to have **all calls** executed "in parallel""!!

Why dont you remove Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5) and give the Dispatchers.IO for coroutine run by his self?

```
runBlocking {
  (1..1000).forEach {
    launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
      delay(100)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `Dispatcher.IO` a thread pool in the end? Also limited by the number of threads (and might even be shared with other workflows as well)? (Saying that, it has been a while since I experimented with Kotlin and moved away from it since the question was asked).